# Helm install fails and gives "Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot patch "cp-kong-init-migrations""

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, kong

I am trying to automate the deployment of Kong using Helm in a kubernetes cluster through a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. Everything works fine until I run this command "helm install cp charts/kong -n kong -f cp.yaml".

This is part of my cp-kong-init-migrations manifest:

```
 apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod                                                                                                                                                 
  metadata:                                                                                                                                                 
    annotations:                                                                                                                                            
      kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged                                                                                                                     
      sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"                                                                                                                      
    creationTimestamp: "2023-02-14T20:05:38Z"                                                                                                               
    generateName: cp-kong-init-migrations-                                                                                                                  
    labels:                                                                                                                                                 
      app.kubernetes.io/component: init-migrations                                                                                                          
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cp                                                                                                                        
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm                                                                                                                   
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kong                                                                                                                          
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "3.1"                                                                                                                      
      controller-uid: <uid>                                                                                                   
      helm.sh/chart: kong-2.15.3                                                                                                                            
      job-name: cp-kong-init-migrations                                                                                                                     
    name: cp-kong-init-migrations-6xfxz                                                                                                                     
    namespace: kong                                                                                                                                         
    ownerReferences:                                                                                                                                        
    - apiVersion: batch/v1                                                                                                                                  
      blockOwnerDeletion: true                                                                                                                             
      controller: true                                                                                                                                      
      kind: Job                                                                                                                                             
      name: cp-kong-init-migrations                                                                                                                         
      uid: <uid>                                                                                                             
    resourceVersion: "33448747"                                                                                                                             
    uid: <uid>                                                                                                               
  spec:                                                                                                                                                     
    automountServiceAccountToken: true                                                                                                                      
    containers:                                                                                                                                             
    - args:                                                                                                                                                 
      - kong                                                                                                                                                
      - migrations                                                                                                                                          
      - bootstrap                                                                                                                                           
      env:
```

The pipeline logs display this error (this is just a small piece of it):

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot patch "cp-kong-init-migrations" with kind Job: Job.batch "cp-kong-init-migrations" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"kong-init-migrations", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil) ....
```

I have tried looking this error up but there isn't much out there on this so if anyone has any advice that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Could you add `cp-kong-init-migrations` job manifest to the question?

Comment: Yes, just added @Andromeda

Comment: I think it is for `pod` not `job`. If your helm repo is public, sharing it also would help.

Comment: @Andromeda I found this issue, my helm version and kubernetes versions were not compatible. I was using helm 3.11 with kubernetes 1.22. I downgraded to helm 3.10 and it ran perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was version compatability between kubernetes and its tools. I was trying to use helm version 3.11 on a kubernetes cluster version 1.22 and they are not compatible. You can see which helm version are supported by kubernetes with this chart [https://helm.sh/docs/topics/version_skew/#:~:text=As%20of%20Helm%203%2C%20Helm%20is%20assumed%20to,to%20be%20compatible%20with%20n-1%20versions%20of%20Kubernetes](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/version_skew/#:%7E:text=As%20of%20Helm%203%2C%20Helm%20is%20assumed%20to,to%20be%20compatible%20with%20n-1%20versions%20of%20Kubernetes).

I solved the problem by downgrading helm version to 3.10.